# クリックしたら、色の変化を維持したい。

Tags: html, css

http://uu-hokkaido.cedars.jp/renewal.shtml

こちらのメインビジュアルの北海道の地図の上のピンクの丸をクリックすると、
濃いピンクの色が、マウスを丸から移動しても維持し続けるようにするにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

今は、:hoverにしていますが、
:active
:focus
:focus-within
:visited

全部試しましたが上手くいきませんでした。

お分かりになる方いましたら、ご教授願います。

Comment: どの程度の期間、条件でそれを維持したいのですか？

Comment: 他の場所を　クリックするまで維持したいです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:focus` 擬似クラスによって、フォーカスを持っている要素に対して装飾を行うことが出来ます。

ここで、要素がフォーカス可能な領域となるためには、**以下の条件を満たす必要があります**<sup>[[1]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#data-model)</sup>。実際は別の条件によってもフォーカス可能な要素となり得ますが、今回は紹介しません。

- 該当の要素にタブインデックスフォーカスフラグがセットされている
- 該当の要素がレンダリングされているか、関連するキャンバスフォールバックコンテンツとして使用されている
- 要素が無効化されていない
- 要素が不活性でない

> #### § 6.4.2 Data model<sup>[[1]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#data-model)</sup>
>
> - Focusable area:
>   Elements that have their tabindex focus flag set, that are not actually disabled, that are not expressly inert, and that are either being rendered or being used as relevant canvas fallback content.
> - DOM anchor
>   The element itself.

---

そして、今回の「北海道の地図の上のピンクの丸」は、これらの条件のうち、**最初の 1 つ以外を満たしています**。そこで、「北海道の地図の上のピンクの丸」を表現する `div` 要素に対して **`tabindex` 属性を付与する**ことで、フォーカス擬似要素による装飾を行うことが出来ます。

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

li:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(238, 156, 184, 0.48);
}

div:focus {
  background: rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.71);
  /* 最初と最後の div 要素は、フォーカス可能領域としての条件を満たしていないため、フォーカス出来ない */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div role="button"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div role="button" tabindex="-1"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div role="button" tabindex="-1"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div role="button" tabindex="-1"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div role="button"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: supa様　解決できました。どうもありがとうございました。感謝致します。

Comment: @Veronica さん> 解決されたようで良かったです。もし解決されたのであれば、お手数ですが、「回答の横側にあるチェックマーク」をクリックし、質問を解決済みにしていただけませんか？

Comment: ご教授頂きまして、どうもありがとうございました。